# C++: How to initialize static member variables which are not integral types?

Tags: c++, static, initialization

How can I initialize a static object in c++? I'm looking for something like static block in java.

I tried this:

Foo.hpp

```
class Foo{
    public:
    static Bar b;
    static String s;
    static Bar setB();
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
Bar Foo::b = Foo::setB();
String Foo::s = "something";
Bar Foo::setB()
{
    Bar bb;
    bb.use(s);
    return bb;
}
```

There is no compile error, but it's not working.

Many thanks

Comment: I do not know why it's not working, because it should :)

Comment: Thank you guys, you are right, I should have posted the actual code (It was complicated with long names, just didn't want to mess the question). It works. The problem was that I was using another static variable in the setB function which was initialized after b.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
class Foo{
    public:
    static Bar b;
    static Bar setB();
}
```

Your comment:

> There is no compile error

That is **not correct**. It *can not* compile, due to missing semicolon.

When that is pointed out, most SO posters then claim in some comment that "but it's just a typing mistake, I will correct it", thus *compounding* the error by invalidating already posted answers.

In short, when you post code, do copy and paste the **real code**. Don't retype it. Copy and paste.

Now, to the core question, the continuation of the above comment, that

> it's not working.

Well, assuming that your *real code* has the appropriate semicolons, and that `Bar` is defined, etc., then also that part is just **plain wrong**.

I tested it with Visual C++ and MingW g++, and (when corrected for semicolons etc.) it works just OK.

Comment: You are right, I should have posted the actual code. Now I've edited the post, though I found the problem, and post it as a comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Bar` needs a no-args constructor so that it can initialize itself to the expected value.

No need for `Foo::setBar()` since Foo will already have the `Bar` instance.

Comment: I tried to simplify the code. The `Bar b` was actually a list, which some strings should be inserted to it. So I need the `setBar()`. I edited the post, though found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works, other than the fact that you didn't actually initialize anything:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
public:
    static int b;
    static int setB();
};

int Foo::b = Foo::setB();
int Foo::setB()
{
    int bb;
    bb = 42;  // Not in your example
    return bb;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << 42 << std::endl;
}
```

This prints 42.  (Note that I've changed "Bar" to "int" since you didn't post a definition of Bar.)

Comment: I hope it prints 42, because 42 is explicitly printed :-)

Answer (score 0):

root cause : no semicolon at the end of the class definition. Works perfectly when I put one.

suggestions: Please give more code(the whole if possible) whenever you ask questions and please don't type the code again instead just copy paste it.